# Why does Dreamweaver CS6 strip whitespace on FTP upload to remote server

Tags: ftp, dreamweaver

When I use DW to upload files to my remote server via FTP this is what it does to the file. Basically it strips all of the whitespace/ line breaks  from the file.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/xxxxx.php'); ?><?php// *** Validate request to login to this site.if (!isset($_SESSION)) {  session_start();}?><!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Untitled Document</title></head><body><?php echo session_id();?><br><?php$_SESSION['test']++;echo $_SESSION['test'];?></body></html>
```

Usually I use cyberduck, but thought it would be easier to just transfer from within DW,  Has anyone had this issue, or know why this happens.  I'm thinking its a setting somewhere that I've overlooked. Thanks

Comment: What's the OS on client side, OS on server side?

Comment: I'm on a mac uploading to cpanel